# Получение элемента из списка элементов, наследуемых от одного класса

Tags: c#

Совсем недавно начал писать несколько классов: Human, Food, оба наследуются от GameObject.

В классе Human есть метод EatFood, который берёт в себя элемент класса Food.

В данной части кода я проверяю, что элемент под индексом objIndex класса Food.

```
if (gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex) is Food)
            this.EatFood(gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex));
```

Однако, компилятор выдаёт ошибку преобразования GameObject в Food.

Пишу код вторую неделю, а ООП код - второй день, так что не до конца понимаю, почему после проверки типа нельзя отправить этот элемент в качестве класса Food.

Comment: Почитайте про форматирование и не используйте так много выделения полужирным: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/

Comment: @AK Благодарю, приму к сведению!

Comment: Кстати, вместо `<br>` можно просто делать [пустую строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/862869/revisions).

Comment: @AK, неа, пустая строка и `<br>` имеют разный эффект. Чтобы получить эффект аналогичный `<br>` необходимо поставить 2 пробела на конце строки, тогда следующая будет точно перенесена. Пустая строка же добавляет конец абзаца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `is` в текущем виде не приводит значение, а только проверяет.

Поэтому внутри `if` необходимо этот объект привести явно либо

```
this.EatFood(gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex) as Food);
```

либо

```
this.EatFood((Food)gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex));
```

---

В последних версиях языка добавилась возможность сохранить [результат `is`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression), и код выходит проще:

```
if (gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex) is Food food)
    this.EatFood(food);
```

Answer (score 2):

У нас статическая типизация, поэтому проверка не меняет тип и приведение делать нужно явно:

```
if (gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex) is Food)
    this.EatFood((Food)gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex));
```

В последних версиях языка это можно переписать с использованием сопоставления с образцом:

```
if (gamefield.field.ElementAt(objIndex) is Food food)
    this.EatFood(food);
```